# How to fix "failed to throw an IllArgumentException" in java

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to write a program that sorts a list of two integers so that the elements are in ascending order, the size of the list remains unchanged, and gives an IllegalArgumentException if the size of list is not equal to 2.

This is what I have:

```
public static void sort2(List<Integer> t) { //t is a the list
        if(t.size() < 3) {
            Collections.sort(t);
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        else if (t.size() == 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("List is empty");
        }
}
```

However, when I do the JUnit test the sorting passes, but the exception test fails. The test is as follows:

```
public void test10a_sort2() {
    ArrayList<Integer> t = new ArrayList<>();
    String error = "lab0.sort2(t) failed to throw an IllegalArgumentException";
    try {
      lab0.sort2(t);
      fail(error);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException x) {
      // do nothing
    }
    catch (Exception x) {
      fail("lab0.sort2(t) threw the wrong kind of exception");
    }

    t.add(1);
    try {
      lab0.sort2(t);
      fail(error);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException x) {
      // do nothing
    }
    catch (Exception x) {
      fail("lab0.sort2(t) threw the wrong kind of exception" + x);
    }

    t.add(2);
    t.add(3);
    try {
      lab0.sort2(t);
      fail(error);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException x) {
      // do nothing
    }
    catch (Exception x) {
      fail("lab0.sort2(t) threw the wrong kind of exception");
    }
  }
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I also tried using the try catch but did not seem to work as well.

Comment: Your description says "IllegalArgumentException if the size of list **is not equal to 2**". Have a look at the condition you're checking in your method. Is it doing what was described?

Comment: Please give us your log of the exception or tell us in which line the error is raised. You have several IllegalArgumentExceptions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(t.size() < 3) {
        // ...
    }
    else if (t.size() == 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("List is empty");
    }
```

You will only throw the exception if the first condition is false and the second is true, i.e. `t.size() >= 3 && t.size() == 2`. That's clearly impossible, so the exception will never be thrown.

---

Put the condition that throws the exception first:

```
if (t.size() != 2) {
  throw ...
}
```

and then put the stuff to do if the size *is* 2 after.